# best strategy for attaching arbitrary threads to Android JVM

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I find myself needing to call back into the JVM from arbitrary native 
threads that may or may not be long-lived.  It's easy enough call 
AttachCurrentThread prior to every Java method invocation on the 
assumption that it's a (presumably fast) no op if the thread's already 
attached, but I find myself wondering what the JVM does with attached 
native threads when they go away somewhere in native-land without 
being officially detached.  Or in other words, is this going to be a 
problem?  If so, then I find myself wondering about the overhead of 
attaching/detaching for each Java method invocation.  Ideally each 
thread would just register itself upon startup and detach on shutdown 
but again, I'm writing code that must be callable from arbitrary 
threads running code that has no idea it's running inside of Android, 
so that's not a realistic option in this case.

Any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find myself wondering what the JVM does with attached native threads when they go away somewhere in native-land without being officially detached.

The regular VM shuts down when all non-daemon threads have exited.  Attaching a thread without detaching means that the VM cannot exit and has to wait for your thread to detach first. This is just a general case of VM, though. In Android it shouldn't be a problem, as apps don't really "exit". [Source](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/3d80b790e24cb9e2/0b30b112f75598ac?pli=1).

**But** detaching threads is highly recommended for proper memory management (see an [official recommendation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/jni.html#threads)).

> I'm writing code that must be callable from arbitrary threads running code that has no idea it's running inside of Android, so that's not a realistic option in this case.

Actually, the implementation of a self-detaching thread is quite easy. Pass "destructor" reference to `pthread_key_create(destKey_, threadDestructor);` and inside this "destructor" call JNI method `cached_jvm->DetachCurrentThread();`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, these threads are often-times created and destroyed by library code that I have no control of, and yet they find themselves needing to call my library and thus into JNI.  Or in other words, I have no access to a destructor (if it exists at all) ...

Comment: Oh, wait.  I think I see what you're getting at, per the Android Developer site.  I imagine that will work.  Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread#comment41724806_26534926. **TL;NR**: proper detach is essential on Android.