# Android JNI - Call AttachCurrentThread without DetachCurrentThread

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been reading about JNI stuff and can't seem to figure out what happens if a thread starts -> calls AttachCurrentThread() -> make some JNI calls -> thread exit.

Ideally, we should call DetachCurrentThread() before thread exits, however, what are the implications if the app doesn't do that? Would it cause memory leak or any other problem?

Comment: Note that you should only call `DetachCurrentThread()` if you attached the thread.  Behavior detaching the current thread if it's a JVM-owned thread is undefined.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not calling `DetachCurrentThread()` will definitely cause a memory leak; other consequences are JVM-specific, and <s>probably irrelevant for Android apps, where the JVM shuts down when the process exits</s>. There are quite a few C++ wrappers that help to manage thread Attach/Detach, see for example:  http://w01fe.com/blog/2009/05/c-callbacks-into-java-via-jni-made-easyier

**Update:** 1000 thanks to **[fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden)** for the eye-opening *[link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Thread.cpp)*; on Dalvik, a  thread that exits without calling `DetachCurrentThread()`, brings the whole VM and the process crashing down.

Here is the logcat from the official emulator, my code based on the [`HelloJni`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ndk/samples/hello-jni) sample from NDK:

```
10-26 04:16:25.853: D/dalvikvm(1554): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.hellojni-2/libhello-jni.so 0xb3d264f0
10-26 04:16:25.893: D/dalvikvm(1554): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.hellojni-2/libhello-jni.so 0xb3d264f0
10-26 04:16:25.893: D/dalvikvm(1554): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.hellojni-2/libhello-jni.so 0xb3d264f0, skipping init
10-26 04:16:26.463: D/gralloc_goldfish(1554): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-26 04:16:31.033: D/threadFunction(1554): Attaching
10-26 04:16:31.173: D/threadFunction(1554): Not Detaching
10-26 04:16:31.183: D/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=11: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
10-26 04:16:31.193: D/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=11: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=1)
10-26 04:16:31.193: E/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=11: native thread exited without detaching
10-26 04:16:31.193: E/dalvikvm(1554): VM aborting
10-26 04:16:31.213: A/libc(1554): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000612 (code=-6), thread 1567 (xample.hellojni)
```

Here is the relevant function added to [`hello-jni.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ndk/samples/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c):

```
static JavaVM* jvm = 0;
static jobject activity = 0; // GlobalRef

void* threadFunction(void* irrelevant)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    usleep(5000000);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "threadFunction", "Attaching");

    (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env, NULL);

    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, activity);
    jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "finish", "()V" );
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, activity, methodID);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "threadFunction", "Not Detaching");
//    (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
}

jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);
    activity = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thiz);

    pthread_t hThread;
    pthread_create(&hThread, NULL, &threadFunction, NULL);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

A nice implementation of this strategy can be found in WebRTC [git repo](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/sdk/android/src/jni/jvm.cc#106).

Comment: I can't access the link.

Comment: Also, if I create a large number of threads and call attachcurrentthread without detach, then memory leak is possible. However, what happens if there are a few long running threads and they exit without calling detachcurrentthread. What would be the impact? Does it not automatically detach itself once it has exited?

Comment: No, the threads do not "automatically detach themselves" until the process (and JVM, on Android both happen at the same time) is shut down. As I mentioned, on other platforms, where JVM may outlive a process or _vice versa_, the effect may be more painful. Also, the leak may be very significant, this depends on how the particular thread handles its JNI.

Comment: I see. One more follow up question. Can a thread call attach and detach multiple times? Would that cause any issues? OR I should only call attach when thread is created and then call detach when it exits?

Comment: Yes, it can attach and detach, and attach and detach again; this introduces some overhead, but the consequences should be weighted for each particular situation.

Comment: If a thread attaches and then halts without detaching, the Dalivk VM will abort, so that resource leaks do not go unnoticed.  Take a look at threadExitCheck(), line 1035 in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Thread.cpp .

Comment: @fadden: 1000 thanks, indeed! I just tried this, and yes, the app went crashing down when I removed an innocent `DetachCurrentThread()` call. Please see update.

Comment: One note: from reading the JNI source code, it's clear that attach/detach is not recursive. So you should call `GetEnv()` first, and only call `AttachCurrentThread()/DetachCurrentThread()` if it failed. Otherwise, you'll be in a situation where a function was called in a scope where there was already a valid JNIEnv but you detached it and now any functions that follow are screwed. (Someone correct me if I've missed something.)

Comment: Leaving out DetachCurrentThread() probably creates memory leaks, suggest synchronisation or additional call to create the thread.