# JNI Environment Pointer

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java class in which I have a function which must be called from my C code.
The function is the following:

```
public void endTrial(){
    //Code
}
```

So I have created the following code in my C file:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL package_endTrialJava();
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL package_endTrialJava(){
    jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
    env->CallVoidMethod(javaObjectRef, javaMethodRef);
}
```

But to be able to call this function with the `env` variable, I have created this function which is called whenever I launch my program.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL package_initJNI(JNIEnv* en, jobject ob)
{
    try {
        // LOGD("(JNI) [FluidMechanics] loadVelocityDataSet()");

        if (!App::getInstance())
            throw std::runtime_error("init() was not called");

        if (App::getType() != App::APP_TYPE_FLUID)
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong application type");


        FluidMechanics* instance = dynamic_cast<FluidMechanics*>(App::getInstance());
        android_assert(instance);
        jclass dataClass = en->FindClass("fr/limsi/ARViewer/MainActivity");
        javaClassRef = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
        javaMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(javaClassRef, "endTrial", "()V");

        env = en ;
        obj = ob ;        

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        throwJavaException(env, e.what());
    }
}
```

And I have these global variables declared in my code as well, so that the call to initJNI() can store the JNIEnv variable.

```
JNIEnv* env ;
jobject obj ;
```

But my program crashed so it seems that storing the `JNIEnv` variable does not work. Is there any workaround then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot/should not store the `JNIEnv` pointer. Is is only valid for the current thread.
But you can use `AttachCurrentThread` to get a `JNIEnv`pointer for your current thread.
Or if you know that it is already attached you can use `GetEnv`.
And beside of that you do not mention how you use the global `jobject obj` but keep in mind that you need to take care that those references stay valid long enough. `NewGlobalRef` is the way to go.

Untested:

```
JavaVM* g_jvm = 0;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL package_initJNI(JNIEnv* en, jobject ob)
{
    ....
    // insted of the env store the VM
    en->GetJavaVM(&g_jvm);
    obj = en->NewGlobalRef(ob); // I don't think you need this
    // and at some point you must delete it again
    ....
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL package_endTrialJava(){
    JNIEnv* env;
    g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL); // check error etc
    jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
    // this line makes not much sense. I think you don't need it if you use the global
    // with the global it would be more like this
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj javaMethodRef);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have added the missing part of the code in my initJNI function to show how I use the jobject. Could you post code as well to illustrate how to use it in my example?

Comment: @LBes: I guess it should be like this. I don't understand your example completely. It seems that you are trying to create a new object but you also store an object. And your `NewObject`call is not with a Ctor method ref. So this looks suspicious. But I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your code, I'm gonna try to figure this out ASAP. But what do you mean by "using the global" in your comment in the code?

Comment: @LBes: Well you store a jobject in a global variable. And you create a new one in your method and do not use the global jobject. So I assumed that you do not need to call `NewObject` and just use the global jobject. But this is something you must know.

Comment: So I tried this piece of code (with the given edit that I submitted on your answer), but I get "Runtime aborting... (Aborting thread was not attached to runtime!) Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock" whenever I call  g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

Comment: This must be something android specific. I did not do much with android lately so I cannot tell how this can happen.

Comment: indeed this was something android specific. For other people who may have errors with that, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread Thanks for your answer. I mark as accepted