# How can I call JNIEnv function from Kotlin/Native

Tags: java-native-interface, kotlin-native

`jni.h` provide this

```c
struct JNINativeInterface_ {
    ...
    jint (JNICALL *GetVersion)(JNIEnv *env);
    ...
}
```

to call it in `C` can be written as

```c
void test(JNIEnv *env){
    // C
    jint version = (*env)->GetVersion(env);

    // C++
    // jint version = env->GetVersion(); 
}
```

and then how can I do it in kotlin?

```kotlin
fun test(env: CPointer<JNIEnvVar>){
    val version = // how?
}
```

After searching answer in google there are few example for `Kotlin/Native` with `JNI` but they're just basic example please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need something like `env.pointed.pointed!!.GetVersion!!.invoke(env)!!`. It's not really that difficult to find examples. Google for _Kotlin/Native jnienvvar_.

Comment: @Michael it's work thanks

Comment: Somebody should post this as an answer. Bump up the S/O stats. I think "unanswered questions" is a stat, and doesn't look good for a platform :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael.

Long answer is

```kotlin
fun test(env: CPointer<JNIEnvVar>){
    // getting "JNINativeInterface_" reference from CPointer<JNIEnvVar> by 
    val jni:JNINativeInterface_ = env.pointed.pointed!!

    // get function reference from JNINativeInterface_
    // IntelliJ can help to find existing methods
    val func = jni.GetVersion!! 

    // call a function
    var version = func.invoke(env)

    // above expression can be simplify as
    version = env.pointed.pointed!!.GetVersion!!(env)!!
}
```

hope this can help somebody to understand
Kotlin/Native .

Comment: Where does the `env` variable come from?  You aren't *caching* the value from another JNI call, are you?  Because you can't do that safely...

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for feedback. I updated my answer for env variable.

Comment: [You can't cache a `JNIEnv` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976639/jni-environment-pointer).  You either get it passed to you directly from the JVM, or you attach/detach the current thread to the JVM.  No other `JNIEnv` variable is going to be valid.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes this methods should call from JVM's native-method. My purpose is just want to know what I can do with `CPointer<JNIEnvVar>` that passed from JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless4024's answer is correct, but I struggled to get it too work!  The problem was that JNIEnvVar was undefined and it wasn't clear what I need to do to get that to resolve.  I'll just augment Wireless4024's  answer with what you need to do to be able to reference JNI structures in kotlin/native functions.

You need to add a dependency to the kotlin "std-jdk8".  Here's an gradle kts script code snippet for doing that

```
kotlin {
    ...
   sourceSets {
       nativeMain.dependencies {
            implementation (kotlin("std-jdk8))
   }
    ...
}
```

An easy mistake since your planning on making native code, so you might not think the you need the kotlin std-jdk8 dependency.